# How to pass id value with jquery to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to pass an id value to a php script with jquery.

So, I was trying to create a link:

```
<a href="#" id="superman">Superman</a>
```

and when this link is clicked, I would like jquery to grab the id value and place it in the php script or php grabs the id? im not sure the best way.

I want the id value so it can be placed in a mysql query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM hero_db WHERE category="superman"
```

So, i get the id and place it in for the category as seen above.

I have trying many things, but am unfamiliar with jquery but trying to learn as much as I can.

Thank you for any help on this.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to load HTML when the link is clicked. If so you need markup something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="superman" class="loaddata">Superman</a>

<div id="superman_data">
</div>
```

with Javascript:

```
$("a.loaddata").click(function() {
  $("#" + this.id + "_data").load('/loaddata.php', {id: this.id});
  return false;
});
```

What this does is binds an event listener to all anchors with a class of "loaddata". When it's clicked on, the ID is passed to loaddata.php. That script should return HTML. It is loaded into the named div.

There are various [jQuery Ajax methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). Which one you use depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('http://PHP_SCRIPT_URL', {id: $('a.yourlik').attr('id')});
```